# MongoDB huge document or multiple queries

Tags: mongodb, database-design, social-networking, database

I've got a little question. I want to create a software where users can like posts. Now I was wondering how to save the likes. I could do this like that:

```
{
    _id:"123456789",
    text:"test",
    likes:[
        {
            username:"User1"
        },
        {
            username:"User2"
        }
    ]
}
```

With this solution I have an inner array. But when I want to query this post and this post has a massiv amount of likes, it loads every time the whole object with the big array. And I think this takes much performance. An advantage is that I can get the post and also check if I have liked this post.

And now I have this solution:

```
{
    _id="123456789",
    text:"test"
}
```

This is the post with no likes in it. And in another collection like this:

```
{
    _id="111111111",
    username:"User1",
    postId:"123456789"
}
{
    _id="222222222",
    username:"User2",
    postId:"123456789"
}
```

are the likes. The advantage is here that you can load the smaller objects but every like object needs a lot of disk space. And you can't get with one single query the post and the information that I have liked it. So if I want to get 20 posts I can't  go with just one query, I will need 21.

So what's the better whay to go with? Or is there also another, better solution? And how is this problem solved by Instagram for example. You get the post, see if you have liked it, it has over 1M likes, etc. The inner array would be huge.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Your schema design to have post as document _id and adding users as documents in inner array, will definitely have impact on performance, since if the post has over 1M likes, etc and the inner array would be huge.

Alternate approach of my preference

Have two collections User and Post

**User schema**

```
{
  _id: 1,
  user_id: "1234ABC",
  user_name: "MyFriend",
  postsLiked: [
    {
       post: 1 
    }
  ],
  postsDisLiked: [
    {
       post: 2
    }
  ]
}
```

**Posts Schema**

```
{
  _id: 1,
  post_name: "My first article",
  author: "Best",
  likesCount: 25,
  dislikesCount: 10
}
{
  _id: 2,
  post_name: "Why Bored",
  author: "Best",
  likesCount: 10,
  dislikesCount: 7
}
```

This schema designed based on the assumption that a post getting 1Million likes can be often, whereas an user likes, dislikes 1Million posts is lesser.

To maintain the data of likes and dislikes we need to do the following

```
User likes a post
    if post not exists in postsLiked array and post not in postsDisLiked array    
        Add the post in postsLiked array of User Document
    if post in postsDisLiked array
        Remove the post in postsDisLiked array and add it in postsLiked array
    if post in postsLiked array
        Do nothing

User dislikes a post
    if post not exists in postsLiked array and post not in postsDisLiked array    
        Add the post in postsDisLiked array of User Document
    if post in postsLiked array
        Remove the post in postsLiked array and add it in postsDisLiked array
    if post in postsDisLiked array
        Do nothing
```

If we want to show users and his/her liked/disliked posts together in a view user [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Thank you, looks good. But can I get a boolean with $lookup to check if the array in user contains the post id? So than I can check it with one query? Because I think that it just gets some values from another collection, isn't it?

Comment: $exists - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/ will help you in getting a boolean value. But as far as I know we cannot check and update/delete in a single query.